# I am trying to fetch Datetime attribute from SQL SERVER.SSMS using stored procedure and trying to assign dateofopening variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

```cs
public void SearchAccount(int accountno,out DateTime dateofopening)
{
    conn = ConnectionEstablisher.getconnection();
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("account_search", conn);//account_search - stored procedure name
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno);//searching account no in table
            
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateofopening",SqlDbType.DateTime));
    cmd.Parameters["@dateofopening"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            
    object v = cmd.Parameters[parameterName: dateofopening];
    dateofopening = (datetime)v;

    return;
}
```

```sql
create proc [dbo].[account_search]  //stored procedure in ssms
    @accountno int,
    @dateofopening datetime output
as
begin 
    select 
        @dateofopening = DateOfOpening 
    from Accounts 
    where AccountNo=@accountno
end
```

> Error:Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
> at ConsoleApp7.AccountOperations.SearchAccount(DateTime& dateofopening) in C:\Users\RAHUL\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\AccountOperations.cs:line 94

Comment: Before even getting to what you're doing with the output, where do you execute the command? I see you open a connection, and set up some parameters, but when does SQL Server ever see the command? Also please don't use `AddWithValue()`: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: error: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)

Comment: DBNull.Value is not a DateTime. Check for `v == DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

There are **several** big issues in that code. I've posted fixes below, with comments explaining the changes.

But the big thing is **the query never runs**. You must call `ExecuteReader()`, or `ExecuteScalar()`, or `ExectueNonQuery()`, or `Fill()` via a DataAdapter, before the query will actually run on the server.

```
//functions should accept inputs and return outputs.
public DateTime SearchAccount(int accountno)
{
    object result = null;

    // Only get the STRING, not the actual connection!
    var connectionString = ConnectionEstablisher.getConnectionString();

    // You should create a **brand new connection object** for most queries. Really!
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("account_search", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Don't use AddWithValue()! It can really hurt performance if you're not careful.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@accountno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = accountno;

        //Wait as long as possible to open connection, let it close as early as possible
        conn.Open();

        //Actually **run the query!**
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    } //end of the using block guarantees the connection will close, **even if an exception is thrown**

    //check for both null (no records returned from dB) and DBNull (NULL value returned from DB)
    if (result == null || result == DBNull.Value) return default(DateTime);

    //result ALREADY is a DateTime, so just cast to tell the compiler. Don't use an expensive conversion
    return (DateTime)result;
}
```

Of course, you must also change the calling code to now accept (and check) the result of this function.

Here's the changed SQL to go with it:

```sql
create proc [dbo].[account_search]  //stored procedure in ssms
    @accountno int
as
begin 
    select DateOfOpening 
    from Accounts 
    where AccountNo=@accountno
end
```

Now I'll list the C# again, but without all the extra comments so you can see it's not really any longer:

```
public DateTime SearchAccount(int accountno)
{
    object result = null;

    var connectionString = ConnectionEstablisher.getConnectionString();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("account_search", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@accountno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = accountno;

        conn.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    } 
    if (result == null || result == DBNull.Value) return default(DateTime);
    return (DateTime)result;
}
```

We could simplify the code further if we also structure the SQL so `null` and `DBNull` and not really possible

As a bonus, here's a link to help explain why you should not try to re-use the connection object throughout the application:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query/398790#398790

Answer (score -2):

dateofopening= Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.Parameters["@dateofopening"].Value.ToString());